# How to find Service Stars on non-gun or class weapons/objects?

Tags: battlefield-3

As the title says. Is there a way for me to find out what **Service Stars** I have for things like grenade and knife?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service stars are still awarded for every 100 kills. So if you go on Battlelog, you can see how many kills you have with those items. It will show you the number of service stars for the knife, if it doesn't for some of the equipment you can calculate it by the number of sets of 100 kills you have with that weapon.

Comment: Hey, emm I was talking about Xbox wise. But still. I have over 212 tags taken yet I don't even have 1 service star for the knife

Comment: I don't recall there being a way for you to do it on the Xbox. The only way I've ever seen the number of service stars in-game is right after you earn one, in the game summary screen it will show you the number of times you took that service star.

Comment: The dogtag count is a little off, but it shouldn't be off that much for you to not have even one star

Comment: According to [here](http://bf3stats.com/stats_360/xCharkz) (and on Battlelog), it only lists you at 82 dogtags, though you do have 101 kills and a service star. I don't know if there is a discrepancy in-game

Comment: It says I have it for the ACB-90 but I only have the standard knife.

Comment: Also in game, I went into dogtags and it says on the bottom right 2xx dog tags taken the "xx" standing for numbers I can't remember but it was in the 200s. Is there any other way of getting dog tags from people?

Comment: Ah, there is no difference in counting for the ACB-90 and standard knife. It may have glitched and counted for the ACB-90 instead, but the totals are the same. Certain "counts" of dogtags taken will count front and back dogtags as two separate ones. This will give you a much higher total dogtags than the number of people killed by taking their tags